# Baseline Equivalency & Validity of Exploratory Analysis

Tags: interaction, equivalence

In a non-random control group study of teachers, I find that treatment and control groups have rather unequal baseline scores (of their self-efficacy). Despite this, there are interesting interactions between the group membership and intervention dosage. In fact, interaction plots show that the treatment group receives much stronger benefits from the intervention than the control group, even though the treatment group's baseline efficacy score was 2SD lower than control. Note that this is an exploratory study.

Do the significant interaction terms have meaning and validity, **despite the lack of baseline equivalency?**

[image: Interaction Effect: Group x Intervention (Y-axis: predicted efficacy score)]

Comment: I got lost at "the treatment group receives much stronger benefits from the intervention than the control group," because I understand a control to mean *by definition* that its members do not receive the intervention at all.  What's going on here?

Comment: Thanks @whuber, point taken.  This is a quasi-experimental design. I measured dosage of activities in both groups, thus we have an interaction effect for both groups.